# if statements should only be cuddled with assignments used in the if statement itself

Tags: go, lint

I'm getting a lint error

> if statements should only be cuddled with assignments used in the if statement itself

The linter is marking the line `if setToWait {` as in bad form.

Here's the code:

```
func doThing() {
    for {
        hasAnyGlobalUnicast := false
        if setToWait {
            for _, nic := range *data.Result {

                // make not if the interface has any global unicast addresses
                for _, addr := range *nic.IPAddresses {
                    if ip := net.ParseIP(addr.Address); ip != nil && ip.IsGlobalUnicast() {
                        hasAnyGlobalUnicast = true
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if hasAnyGlobalUnicast {
            return data, err
        }
    }
}
```

Since the variable `hasAnyGlobalUnicast` is set within the `if setToWait` block and checked after that block completes, shouldn't the linter mandate cuddling of the variable with the `if setToWait` since it's the closest possible scope to where it's being updated?

Comment: Are you using [wsl (Whitespace Linter)](https://github.com/bombsimon/wsl)? You probably want to ask them about [that rule](https://github.com/bombsimon/wsl/blob/master/doc/rules.md#if-statements-should-only-be-cuddled-with-assignments-used-in-the-if-statement-itself). Seems like a bug where it's not detecting the inner if statement.

Comment: I'm pretty new to golang so thought I would ask.  Sorry if I annoyed anyone by writing a -1 question.